# Prevent installing my NuGet package to project with unsupported target framework

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

My NuGet Package targets .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.0.

The .nuspec looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    ...
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0"/>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.0"/>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="...\net40\WinSCPnet.dll" target="lib\net40"/>
    <file src="...\netstandard2.0\WinSCPnet.dll" target="lib\netstandard2.0"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

The assembly included in the package has:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net40;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

But this does not prevent the package from being installed to projects that target different frameworks. For example it can be installed to project targeting .NET Framework 3.5. Obviously it does not work then, as there's no 3.5 version of the assembly.

I assume it should be somehow possible to prevent installing the package to projects targeting unsupported frameworks. For example question [NuGet package not installing in .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62391398/850848) shows that certain packaged failed to install for this very reason. How do I achieve that in my package?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the link. Though I do not understand how does it help me. Can you please explain? Do you mean that the assembly in the NuGet package should have `<TargetFrameworks>net40;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>`? Well, it actually does (I've edited the question). It still does not prevent installing the NuGet package to .NET 3.5 project. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: A package targeting .netstandard2.0 works with any recent framework. I wouldn't bother to much about .net3.5, because that is now really deprecated and out of support. Whoever still uses that one should know what he's doing. Nuget support has made a big step since that was released, so I presume detecting wrong packages is just not properly implemented there.